# Upload .mov video file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm tying to upload video file in .mov file extension other video file such as mp4, flv is working but when tyring to upload .mov it doesn't work.

here is my code :

```
public function add_video(){
    if (isset($_FILES['video']['name']) && $_FILES['video']['name'] != '') {
        unset($config);
        $date = date("ymd");
        $configVideo['upload_path'] = './video';
        $configVideo['max_size'] = '9000000000';
        $configVideo['allowed_types'] = 'mov|avi|flv|wmv|mp3|mp4';
        $configVideo['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        $configVideo['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $video_name = $date.$_FILES['video']['name'];
        $configVideo['file_name'] = $video_name;

        $this->load->library('upload', $configVideo);
        $this->upload->initialize($configVideo);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('video')) {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }else{
            $videoDetails = $this->upload->data();
            $data['video_name']= $configVideo['file_name'];
            $data['video_detail'] = $videoDetails;
            $this->load->view('/upload_video/show', $data);
        }

    }else{
        echo "Please select a file";
    }
  }
```

The error message that I'm getting after upload .mov video is this 
**The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.**
 yes using the * sign in allowed type fix the issue but that would be allowing user to upload all the extention file.

NOTE : I'm using Codeigniter 3.0.4

Comment: Check a permission of the file and give 777 permission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [File Uploading Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) resolves the file extensions from *allowed_types* to actual MIME types using the configuration in `application/config/mimes.php`

What I think is hapenning is that your *.mov* file has a different MIME type than *video/quicktime*. You can check the default configuration here [mimes.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/mimes.php)

**What you need to do is to check the exact MIME type of your file and add it in the mimes.php**.

You can do it by using  [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).

```
echo mime_content_type('filename.mov');
```

Then just change the following line in *application/config/mimes.php*

```
'mov'   =>  'video/quicktime',
```

by adding one or more different MIME types. I was able to fix the same problem by adding video/x-quicktime

```
'mov'   =>  array('video/quicktime', 'video/x-quicktime'),
```

Some of the possible MIME types following this source [Filext.com](http://filext.com/file-extension/MOV) are: *video/quicktime, video/x-quicktime, image/mov, audio/aiff, audio/x-midi, audio/x-wav, video/avi*

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter checks the file content to ensure it is actually of the expected MIME type.

First, verify if the correct MIME is detected for your file, by using this code:

```
// should be "video/quicktime"
$mime = finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $filepath);
```

I assume you are using at least PHP 5.3. Since you can upload other file types, I assume the above code will work without producing errors, otherwise you have to fix MIME detection (e.g. Apache "magic file").

So, normally the only MIME for `.mov` is `video/quicktime`, but if ever you got something else, for example `video/hdmov`, you can add it to `application/config/mimes.php`:

```
// replace:
'mov' => 'video/quicktime',
// with:
'mov' => array('video/quicktime', 'video/hdmov'),
```

If you got an empty result, your file hasn't been recognized (or is somehow broken), try with other `.mov` files to see if they work.

See [`Upload::_file_mime_type()`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Upload.php) for the details on how CodeIgniter tries to detect the file MIME.